# mysql php messaging application

Tags: mysql

**Table strucutre**

```
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mail_box` (
      `msg_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `sender_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `receiver_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `message` text NOT NULL,
      `date` timestamp NOT NULL,
      `attachment` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
      `status` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`msg_id`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=10 ;

    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL
     ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Need the query for listing all the inbox (send and received emails) 
for a particular user group by conversation.

---

### **Query I tried for conversational view**

```
SELECT usr.name as Receiver,usr1.name as Sender, message,date
FROM mail_box 
JOIN users as usr on usr.id = receiver_id 
JOIN users as usr1 on usr1.id = sender_id 
WHERE receiver_id = 1 
GROUP BY sender_id
ORDER BY date DESC
```

This query is listing all the inbox items but not showing the send items.

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there, you're only missing a condition in your `where` clause, in disjunction with the one you already used.

Also, you don't beed that `group by`, because you're not using any aggregation function on the columns you're selecting.

```
select  u1.name as Receiver, u2.name as Sender, mb.message, mb.date
from    mail_box mb
join    users as u1
on      u1.id = mb.receiver_id
join    users as u2
on      u2.id = mb.sender_id
where   mb.receiver_id = 1 or mb.sender_id = 1
order by date desc
```